# Google Map Rates/Charges

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

google map pricing is highly complex. Can someone tell whether the follow will be considered as three map accesses counted for charging. I am using Javascript APIs and render maps on a mobile web app.

1. showing a map in the client
2. Geocode an address
3. Add a marker on the map for the given location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use

1. showing a map in the client using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 is a "Dynamic Maps" load (requires loading the API)
2. Geocode an address is a "Geocoding" access
3. Add a marker on the map for the given location doesn't use any additional quota